# jspfd- autotable: How to add different colors to cells in same column

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to change the color of specific cells depending on a certain value. More specifically, the cells should either appear red, orange or green. I am able to do so if the table conists of only one row by changing the color of the whole column like this:

```
    columnStyles: {
    "columnA": {fillColor: [r,g,b]}
    },
```

Unfortunately, most of the tables I am working with consist of more than one row and thus it is often the case that two cells in the same columns must have different colors. 
How can I change the color of one specific cell? In the documentation of the jspdf-autotable plugin I often read about a cell hook, though I don't know how to use this...

Comment: I succeeded with the createdCell hook:

               `createdCell: function(cell, data) {  

              {if (data.column.dataKey === "id") {  

              {if (data.row.index == 1)  

               {cell.styles.fillColor = [r,g,b]}}}}},`